# jQuery: Trying to iterate through select options values

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm trying to iterate through some select options using jQuery. In doing so, I'm trying to make sure that `each` of those has a `selected` option. From those `selected` options, I want to travel up the DOM tree to the `closest` `<tr>` element and travel back down the DOM tree to `find` the `<span>` element of that row and change the style of a checkmark to represent the completion of that `<select>` form element.

On the `<select>` dropdown, I have an empty value as the default. So I'd like to make sure there is something `>= 0` selected.

I'm still fairly new to jQuery and coding in general so I'm afraid there is something missing that I haven't learned yet.

**application.js**

```
$('#selectId > option').each(function() {

  var formValue = $(this);

  if ( formValue.is(':selected') && formValue.val() >= 0 ) {
  formValue.closest('tr').find('span').removeClass('incomplete').addClass('complete');
  }

});
```

Comment: Did you test your code with your html page ? Does it work ? That's the best way to know if your code corresponds to your needs or not. If you run into a bug, tell us which one et share the html (or a part).

Comment: So the values are all numeric then, as you're testing to see if they are equal to, or greater than zero ?

Comment: @adeneo yes. I don't have to convert them to integers.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it? You have an empty value as default, but you're checking the options, not the selects ?

Comment: why not just `$('#selectId:has(option:selected)').closest('tr'...`

Comment: @adeneo Because I'd like to make sure there is a `selected` option. But if someone selects a value and then changes it back to the empty default, there is still a `selected` option of `""`. The values of the select are from "_0-number_".

Comment: @adeneo actually I just checked that and I could be wrong. Looks like when I change the value back to the default the `selected` value doesn't change immediately. But it does remove the `selected` from `option` when I refresh the page.

Comment: @adeneo I don't think the `:has` method is working for me either. It's only finding the first one rather than iterating through each select form and the first one is an empty default so it shouldn't even be marked as complete. Unless I'm writing it wrong. `$('#selectId:has(option:selected)').closest('tr').find('span').removeClass('incomplete').addClass('complete');`?

Comment: There is only one select, ID's are unique ?

Comment: Oooh, no they don't all have unique ID's. I was using the same ID that was in the HTML. So I have the jQuery code for the check mark to show complete when the value is changed but when the page refreshes the checkmark goes back to incomplete. I'm just trying to show complete when there is a selected value for each of the selects. Maybe I'm going about this all wrong. @adeneo

Comment: If you have the same ID more than once, jQuery will only find the first one, as ID's has to be unique

Comment: Ok I'll re-work this. Thank you for your help @adeneo

Answer (score 0):

**application.js**

```
$('form select option:selected[value!=""]').each(function(index, element) {      
   var span = $(element).closest('tr').find('td:first span');
   $(span).removeClass('incomplete').addClass('complete');
});
```